# How to open Java perspective in Eclipse mars for php?

Tags: java, php, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-mars

I've installed Eclipse Mars for Php, now I'd like to use it to write Java, how can I install JDT (looks like the plugin that I need) to make it show Java Perspective?

I've tried both ways:
install it from Eclipse Marketplace, but I din't find JDT.
Tried to type in the URL for JDT, the closest that I could find is this one: http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/, but it says `Not Found.`

Any help is really appreciated!

[image: Eclipse Mars installation details]

[image]
[image: About Eclipse[![][2]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V76FM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'Help > Install New Software...'

Choose your main software site (`http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars` for Eclipse Mars) in the 'Work with' combo.

In the resulting list choose 'Eclipse Java Development Tools' in the 'Programming Languages' section.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for quick response to my simple question!